# Poison resistance

Tags: dnd-5e, poison

I was in a fight against a young green dragon and I play a War-forged barbarian and had to roll a constitution saving throw to get out of the way and take half damage and the War-forged has poison resistance so how does that work for talking the right amount of damage

Comment: What game are you playing? You mention war forged, so assuming it’s D&D 5e, have you read the [rules about damage resistance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability) yet? If you could be more specific about what you aren’t sure about from those rules, I think we’ll be better equipped to help you.

Comment: Thanks you so much I went to the link and figured out the damage resistances I couldn’t find it in the players handbook easily this helps thank you again

Comment: I added the appropriate tag, thanks to your above comment. Moreover, this question has already been asked, hence I voted to close as duplicate. It is not a big issue, since it may help other users to find the information they are searching for. Anyway, welcome to RPG.SE! You may be interested in taking the [tour] and visit the [help] to have some info in posting questions and answers! happy gaming!

Comment: @KiNgBaDgEr101 For the record, in the physical PHB, you can always flip to the index at the end of the book to find out what page a rule is on.  If you look up "resistance", it'll tell you to look up "damage resistance" instead, which says the rules are on page 197.  WotC has been pretty good about having a really solid index of rules terms, though I don't know why they couldn't just have "resistance" direct you straight to the page.